# Bundle id для тестирования приложения

Tags: google-maps, xcode, ios

Привет.

Вот пытаюсь создать приложение для ios, вставил карту, и он её не показывает, пишет, что нужно bundle id.

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то id исключительно для тестирования, т.к., хоть убейте, но не нашёл где взять этот id. (Само собой, понимаю, что на сайте яблока для разработчиков, но на иностранных сайтов для чайников старые статьи с неактуальными кнопками.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тестирования на телефоне или планшете требуется оплаченая учётная запись разработчика. Для симулятора bundle id может быть почти любой.

Comment: в том то и дело, что в симуляторе не запускается карты http://i.stack.imgur.com/KAzCY.png вот что он показывает вместо карты, хотя ей можно управлять как денамической

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Показывайте то, что вам пишет xCode. Вы уверены, что ваш населённый пункт есть на карте? Переключите режим карты на "Satellite".

Comment: @Zatoichy 2014-12-16 11:55:27.857 tetra[427:5557] Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f8710ca21a0 {data=<CFData 0x7f871271f030 [0x1064fd970]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2014-12-16 11:55:27.857 tetra[427:5557] Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: com.tetra.MyApp

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Ошибка не с bundle id, а с Google API Key. Создайте API Key с bundle id вашего приложения.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: @Zatoichy Спасибо, нужно было просто прописать con.example в bundle id